# How do I extend a HashSet<String> with another HashSet<String>?

Tags: string, rust, hashset, ownership

When I try to extend a `HashSet<String>` with another `HashSet<String>`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
let mut a = HashSet::new();
a.insert("foo".to_owned());
let mut b = HashSet::new();
b.insert("bar".to_owned());
let c = a.extend(&b);
```

I get:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&HashSet<String> as IntoIterator>::Item == String`
 --> src/main.rs:7:11
  |
7 | let c = a.extend(&b);
  |           ^^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `String`
  |
  = note: expected reference `&String`
                found struct `String`
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The accepted answer to the other question doesn't address what's asked here because it recommends `a.extend(&b)` which fails for the OP. It works in the other answer because the other answer uses set elements that are `Copy`. (I was sort of surprised that `a.extend(&b) works for `Copy` elements, I wonder what mechanism allows it.)

Answer (score 10):

`HashSet::extend()` comes from the [`Extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) trait and therefore accepts any iterator (or iterable), not just a set.

If you pass it the reference to a set, that reference is iterable, but the iterator produces references to the elements of the set - in this case `&String`. Since `HashSet::<String>::extend()` expects an iterator that produces actual strings, that doesn't compile. There are two ways to fix the issue:

- by passing the set `b` to `extend` *by value*: `a.extend(b)`;
- by creating an explicit iterator out of `b` using `b.iter()` and *cloning* the values it produces: `a.extend(b.iter().cloned())`.

In the first variant, `b` will be consumed and therefore no longer usable by the caller, but the strings from it will be reused in `a`. In the second variant, `b` will remain usable, but its strings will be copied for storage in `a`.

Note that in neither variant does it make sense to capture the return value of `extend()`, since it operates by side effect and doesn't return a useful value.